# How to change channel of couchbase using Java api

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway, couchbase-java-api

We have some documents in couchbase in which we have channel like follow

```
channel:['job1']
```

Now we have to add another channel that is job2

So channel list will be

```
channel :['job1','job2']
```

Can anyone having idea about how to modify that channel using Java api or using angular ?

Comment: I‘m confused. The syntax you wrote is JavaScript and Angular is a JavaScript framework. Where does Java come into play?

Comment: Nope it's not a JavaScript framework basically couchbase and pouchdb are sync through logic. Actually we need to change the channel of couchbase document. Now we need to check either angular couchbase sync or Java rest api. By the way syntax is in couchbase document which is nosql database

Comment: I guess you are using Couchbase Lite (CBL) on your front end device, right?

Comment: There are many solutions to this, you can do it on the front end or issue a query to the backend.
On the FE you need to have couchbase light functionality available to react then you can simple update the document locally and the sync gateway will replicate it automatically